# Who will get the bounty when the highest votest answer is provided by the bounty-offerer himself?

Tags: discussion, bounties

It's the bounty worth of 400 for a too old question.The current answers on that question doesn't work for newer Ubuntu version. The person who throw the bounty wants an working answer for newer Ubuntu release.

I posted an answer for that question and it got 4 upvotes. Later the person who offered(throw) that bounty comes into the attack by providing an answer(*His answer got 8 upvotes*).

Only these two answers are posted after the bounty was thrown.In this case, who gets the bounty or half of the bounty if that person fails to give the bounty?

Answer (score 2):

The person placing the bounty on the question is not eligible. If he decides not to award the bounty, half the bounty will be awarded to the best answer which is eligible, the criteria for which are described in [this Meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

> - The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2
> - The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter

So in the case you describe above, you'd get half the bounty if it wasn't explicitly awarded.

Comment: The answer must have a score of at least +2.What does it mean ?

Comment: Number of upvotes minus number of downvotes should be +2 or higher.